# When is part size zero in http request of multipart form-data

Tags: http, servlets, file-upload, multipart, spark-java

I'm having an issue in my spark java app where I'm accepting attachments through multipart form data. In the following code sometimes part.getSize() returns zero even though user has uploaded an actual file. When would the part size be zero? even though content length is >0 and it only happens rarely. i cant seem to find a pattern.

```
request.raw().getParts()
    .stream()
    .filter(part -> part.getName().equals("files"))
    .forEach( part -> {
        if (part.getSize() == 0) {
           log.error("Part size zero for {}, content-lengh: {}", part, request.headers("Content-Length"))
        }
        //save file
    });
```

does have anything to do with browser?

Answer (score 0):

See the [FAQ section in Sparks documentation](http://sparkjava.com/documentation#examples-and-faq).

For file upload, you need to a form (I guess you already have that) and a Spark route to handle the form post. handler.

For Spark to be able to process the uploaded file, you have to set a specific request attribute, which allows to use the getPart() method on the raw request:

```java
post("/file-upload", (request, response) -> {
    request.attribute("org.eclipse.jetty.multipartConfig",
        // Specify a temporary directory where Spark can store incoming uploads
        new MultipartConfigElement("/tmp/spark-upload"));

    // The name 'uploaded_file' needs to match the name of the <input type="file">
    // element in the HTML form that uploads the file
    try (InputStream is = request.raw().getPart("uploaded_file").getInputStream()) {
        // Process the incoming file upload
    }

    return "File uploaded";
});
```